# Looking for a loop in my transformations

Tags: functions

You have two transformations on sets.

(1) [64d+30] -> [81d+38]

(2) [256d+138] -> [243d+131]

ie picking a specific value from the 94 ( 64*(1)+30 = 94 ) and applying the first transformation it gets transformed into 119 ( 81*(1)+38 = 119 )

My question is: Can you find a value in a set for which we can apply any number of transformations to lead back to the orignial value or is this impossible.

Note: 2334 is the first value that you can apply the transformation (1) followed by (2)

2334 = 64*(36)+30

applying the first transformation you get

2954

b/c 81*(36)+38 = 2954

2954 can have the second transformation applied because it is part of the starting set.

2954 = 256*(11)+138

Applying the second transformation you get 2804

b/c 2804 = 243*(11)+131

Comment: Even with your examples I cannot discern how these are "transformations on sets."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value $n$, the first transformation calculates $d$ as $d=\frac {n-30}{64}$, then returns $81d+38=\frac {81}{64}(n-30)+38$.  The second then calculates $d'=\frac {\frac {81}{64}(n-30)+38-138}{256}$ and returns $243d'+131=\frac {243}{256}\left(\frac {81}{64}(n-30)-100\right)+131$.  You are then asking for $$n=\frac {243}{256}\left(\frac {81}{64}(n-30)-100\right)+131$$  If we ignore the restriction that the divisions come out even we can solve this for $n$, getting $n=-\frac {614}{3299}$  The fact that this is not an integer shows that this series of transformations cannot return the original number.  As your transformations are linear, there will be just one $n$ that returns the original number for each series of transformations as long as the coefficient on $n$ on the right is not exactly $1$.

Comment: if I didn't limit you to only 2 transormations (1) then (2) but to m transformations (1)(1)(2)(1)(2)... would there potentialy be a solution?

Comment: Potentially, but I suspect not here.  The fact that the numerators are powers of $3$ and the denominators powers of $2$ while the constants are not related to $2$ or $3$ will make it very hard.  When you do a series of transformations it will be hard to get the divisions to come out right, which will force $n$ to be quite large.  Then since the coefficient on the right differs from $1$ it will swamp the constants.  In the example above, the terms with $n$ have a multiplier $-\frac {19683-16384}{16384}$